# problema con liquid-slider en IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, slider

pues eso, resulta que me ha caido una web que usa para toodoos sus slider el liquid-slider que yo ni conozco.
El tema es que uno de los slider me esta dando muchos problemas. 
El link del slider es [este](http://curator.biz/#leistungen). Y el fallo aparece cuando le damos a la flecha para pasar de un slider a otro, el texto con la foto da un salto y se esconde como el la imagen que muestro.[image: fallo en liquidslider]
De verdad que no se que solucion darle, he buscado recursos y nada. Pensaba que podria ser un padding o un Margin, pero tampoco.
A ver s alguno me podeis ayudar.
P.D:Intentare con calma recopilar el codigo, pero como os he dicho, no esta hecha por mi y el codigo es algo desastroso.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que las letras se quedan escondidas? SI es eso, a mí no me pasa en mi navegador. Si es otra cosa, lo mejor sería que pusieras el código para que te puedan ayudar.

Comment: Si, ese es el problema, he detectado que solo pasa con IE explorer y Chrome (ya que firefox parchea el problema). He visto que el slider de start-ups genera un width de 700%y el de Grown-ups de 800%, este ultimo deberia de ser de 780%. Creo que es generado por el propio script, pero no encuentro donde exctamente.